# Intermittent broken copy-paste, Win 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, copy-paste, clipboard

What are common reasons for copy-paste intermittently breaking inside Windows 2008 R2?

Scenario 1:

1. You copy some text (keyboard
   shortcuts or menu click with mouse).
2. When you go to paste it, whatever you previously had on your clipboard
   is still there.

Scenario 2:

1. You copy some text (keyboard shortcuts or menu click with mouse).
2. When you go to paste it, nothing is pasted.

Scenario 3:

1. You copy some text (keyboard shortcuts or menu click with mouse).
2. When you go to paste it, a single line break is pasted.

Other apps in use:

1. Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, TweetDeck, Google Talk, Skype, iTunes, notepad++
2. In the past, when doing programming with Eclipse, I had Scenario 1 happen all the time.
3. Today, inside Visual Studio 2010, I mostly get Scenario 3.

What I'm currently doing to work around this issue

1. Copying about a dozen times (ctrl-c) then pasting. If fails, repeat until it works.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times (fixed by reboot). I've also had copy paste options greyed out on a right click.  I'm curious as to the reason myself.

Comment: Its windows, reboot up to 3 times, fixes most intermittent issues, and no one knows why. Why do you use server software as a desktop OS?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because your clipboard is corrupt. Restart the clipbook service from services.msc and it should fix the issue.

How to restart clipbook service:

- Start -> Run
- Enter services.msc, hit Enter
- In the Services window. look for the service called ClipBook, select it
- On the left pane, click on the link that says 'Restart' or 'Start' if it is not already started.

Hope that helps.